# How to save a "browser-initiated download" file with Powershell System.Net.WebClient and custom user-agent string?

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scripting

I'm running a few commands in the AWS EC2 UserData section when launching an EC2 instance and would like to download a file from Microsoft at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40784 (it's the Visual C++ Redistributable Package for Visual Studio 2013) when it's started.

I have the following command so far:

```
powershell -Command "$cli = New-Object 
System.Net.WebClient;$cli.Headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 
6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 
Safari/537.36';$cli.DownloadFile('https://www.microsoft.com/en-
us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40784', 'C:\UserData\vcredist_arm.exe')"
```

It's using the Powershell System.Net.WebClient method, but it looks like it's downloading the HTML page instead of the executable that is downloaded when you browse to the page first, and then the browser asks you where you want to save the file.

How can I use Powershell to download the actual executable instead of the page at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40784 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you are supplying is the HTTP page so that is why you are downloading that page and not the exe. To work around this you'll have to get a direct link to the file you want to download, usually the page handles this for you but the C# webclient isn't coded to do that.

In this case you can get a directdownload link by:

1. Click the `Click here` link the in `If your download does not start after 30 seconds, Click here`
2. Copy the `Click here` download link to the product you wish to download, in this case `https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/E/6/2E61CFA4-993B-4DD4-91DA-3737CD5CD6E3/vcredist_arm.exe`
3. Use that in place of `https://www.microsoft.com/en-
   us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40784` for the webclient object.